# Is it a short circuit or am I just misunderstanding it?

Tags: rf, transformer

I have [an RF transformer (baluns)](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/ADT1-1+.pdf) on my PCB connected like this:

[image]

When I try checking pin 1 (PRI) with GND with my multimeter it says that pin 1 is connected to the GND.  When I try checking pin 4 and pin 6 they're not connected to each other. Since the schematic here shows that PRI and SEC are same connection, why is pin 1 connected to GND (or maybe pin 3) but pin 4 and 6 are not connected to each other?

[image]

Comment: Are you making these measurements on your PCB - that is, in-situ?

Comment: Did you measure resistance from Pin 4 to 6? What resistance do you measure?

Comment: Please add a link to the datasheet for the transformer into your question. (Don't hide it here in the comments.)

Comment: Are you making a good probe connection to the transformer terminals? Sometimes flux residue can be quite tenacious. Make sure you read 0 ohms when putting both probes on different parts of the pin 4 node, then both probes on pin 6, to make sure you're actually connecting to the pins. You might have a dud transformer, or a dry solder joint, but bad probe contact has to be ruled out first.

Comment: @SteveSh yes i did on my pcb

Comment: @LarsHankeln i didn't measure the resistance i use to thing on multimeter that go beeping if its connected

Comment: @Neil_UK i haven't try it yet , can i also put both probe on pin 1 and pin 3 like you suggest doing on pin 4 and 6

Comment: Please measure resistances. The beeper is only meant to work with hard connections like wires. It won't in general show if a transformer winding is OK - only up to a certain DC resistance. So not very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd expect the pins across each side of a transformer to register as a short from a multimeter. They are connected, usually with a length of wire coiled around a core, which is then magnetically coupled to the opposite windings.
Hence finding that pins 1 and 3 are shorted is quite sensible, but you should see 4 and 6 also shorted. Either there is a problem with the solder connection, or there's a problem with your probing. It can be very tricky sometimes to get a good probe, and as others have said fluxes can get in the way, so do give the board a good clean with IPA or similar.
Also, look for points above the solder to probe, it looks like there's a resistor connected across the secondary winding; if this is THT then it would be a very good point. 
The data sheet doesn't say exactly what resistance the windings have, but you should expect a very low value, and very similar results between them.

Comment: Why would they be shorted or have very low value? Why would they not show 1kohm resistance for example? And it all depends on which resistance threshold the multimeter uses for beeping, and also if other circuitry onboard the PCB like biasing will affect the results.

Comment: The wire used for the windings will have low resistance as any DC resistance in the windings results in power loss. 1k DC resistance would make this transformer useless, at 50Ohms impedance, any more than 0.5Ohm would be poor IMO.
External components can only decrease the DC resistance, it can't increase it. But, seeing as the resistance of the winding will be very low, the external components are unlikely to have a meaningful effect.

Comment: @Justme: RF transformers designed for 50 Ω applications are not going to have thousands of ohms of DC resistance.

Comment: i've test my circuit today , the cause of beeping is like as you said , when i try using resistance measurement its gave me 0.005 ohms which is what i expected from 50 ohm balun , thank you so much

Comment: @Settasak great stuff. If this has helped please consider marking my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the end goal here, but generally, you shouldn't use continuity measurements like these and instead measure impedance at a specific frequency, as per the datasheet, this component should be used between 150kHz and 400MHz (same with the test).

It's possible that there is a large capacitive element on the secondary (that is not depicted) which is keeping the secondary from reaching the point where the continuity tester will "beep".

If you have an unsoldered IC to test, you would expect both windings to have a low impedance at a low frequency.

Comment: A large capacitor would act as an open circuit initially. This might cause a continuity detector to beep initially, and then register an open after the cap charges up, it wouldn't prevent a beep if one was due.

Answer (score -3):

Well you can't measure the transformer in circuit.

The multimeter beeps on primary because the driver has impedance low enough to beep, but secondary impedance is high enough not to beep.

So you are not measuring the transformer, you are measuring the whole circuit that connects to your points of measurement.

Comment: 1:1 transformer should have the same characteristics on both primary and secondary.

Comment: You are mixing impedance and resistance, a multimeter will measure resistance only.

Comment: The transformer is measured in-circuit. We don't know what the circuit looks like and if the circuit is powered or not during multimeter measurements.